# Passing Vars from Javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Is this how you would pass a var from JS to PHP? or is there a better solution. Please could you help with the easiest and most efficient way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var name="John Doe";

document.write(name + "<br>");

</script>

<?php

$name = <script>document.write(name);</script>

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I know this won't work, but how would I do it?

Comment: You misunderstand how PHP and JavaScript work. PHP runs on the server, JavaScript in the browser. What you want to do can't be done - you'd have to make an Ajax call to a separate PHP script to send it data from JavaScript

Comment: You are asking for a better solution? This is not even a bad solution :)

Comment: You can't because javascript is client side, PHP server side

Comment: it looks like you need a tutorial not an answer.

Comment: Thats what I mean, what would be the best solution or any solution?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of similar questions here on SO already, most of which have a useful answer on them. You would have been shown links to them while you were entering this question. A lot of them are also listed down the side panel of this page. Did you actually read any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this:

```
<?php
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
     var name=\"John Doe\";
     document.write(name + \"<br>\");
     </script>";
?>
```

i hope this would be useful

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$name = <script>document.write(name);</script>

?>
```

**You can not do this**

As php is a server side language and js client side,

First it run in server then it output to client were it executes js. So you can not pass values from js to php like in the code above.

If you want to do that you need to use AJAX.

Comment: Downvoters, please explain it.

Comment: This answer is totally correct.

Comment: I downvoted because the answer read just "You can not do this". This is no answer to me. Maybe you should write your whole answer before submitting. Now I can see that you wrote more, but I cannot withdraw my downvote.

Comment: @Amberlamps: Yeah..I was editing the answer :)